# web calls never timing out

Tags: c#, web-services, timeout

I have a number of applications using various web technologies such as SOAP, WCF Services, or just simple XmlReader.  However they all seem to suffer the same problem of missing the timeout and hanging infinitely if the internet connection suffers problems at the wrong time.

I have set the timeout in all scenarios to something small, e.g. for wcf

```
closeTimeout="00:00:15" openTimeout="00:00:15" 
receiveTimeout="00:00:15" sendTimeout="00:00:15"
```

or for soap

```
_Session.Timeout = (int)TIMEOUT.TotalMilliseconds;
```

These timeouts do generally get hit, however it appears there is some special case where if the internet drops out at the right time, the call will hang and never time out (using synchronous calls).

I was considering starting up a timer every time I make a call, and using the appropriate `.Abort()` function if the timer expires to cancel the call.  However, I was wondering if there was a simpler way to fix the issue and ensure the timeout gets hit.

Does anyone know why this occurs, and if so what a clean/simple/good way is to ensure the calls always time out?

Comment: New lead - I think this might have something to do with using web references (which look like the are only from .net 2) instead of service references.  Possibly switching to service references will bring with it more reliable code?  I am trying this anyway to see if it at least fixes those web calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can guess at *why* it occurs, but without giving a solution :(

I *suspect* it's getting caught up on DNS resolution. I've seen various situations where that "doesn't count" - e.g. where it ends up happening on the initiating thread of an asynchronous call, or where it's definitely not been included in timeouts.

If you're able to reproduce this by pulling out your network cable, I'd suggest using Wireshark to confirm my guess - that would at least suggest further avenues for investigation. Maybe there's a DNS timeout somewhere in the .NET stack which is normally infinite but which can be tweaked, for example.

Comment: Interesting info, thanks for that.  I figure it is going to be something low in the stack that will be hard to deal with.  Unfortunately it's pretty hard to reproduce, but I will try to investigate it further.

Comment: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DNSQueryTimeouts`: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc977482 Determines how long the Domain Name System (DNS) client waits for a response to each of the five attempts in the name resolution process.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I cannot find an entry in there on either my Windows 7 or XP boxes called DNSQueryTimeouts.  It looks like the defaults add up to 15 seconds (which is a number I've read elsewhere).  So it should just default to 15 seconds?  If so that's OK and won't be the problem, as a 15 second timeout is fine.  It's the fact that it is *never* timing out and locking up a thread (and I assume port too) which is my major problem.