# C# HttpWebResponse Timeout doesn't work

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebresponse

I have the function to check if website is available.

```
    public bool ConnectionAvailable(string strServer)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest reqFP = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strServer);
            reqFP.Timeout = 10000;
            HttpWebResponse rspFP = (HttpWebResponse)reqFP.GetResponse();

            if (HttpStatusCode.OK == rspFP.StatusCode)
            {
                // HTTP = 200 - Internet connection available, server online
                rspFP.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Other status - Server or connection not available
                rspFP.Close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            // Exception - connection not available
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It's not mine code. I found it in the Net.

The problem is when some website isn't available.
I want to wait x miliseconds (set in reqFP.Timeout), then function should return false.
But everytime I have to wait ~20 seconds (even if i set 10 seconds in "timeout").

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

PS: Sorry for language mistakes.

Comment: I'm sure in the past I've done this with BeginRequest and starting a timer... if the timer fires first it's timed out...

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx):

> A Domain Name System (DNS) query may
>   take up to 15 seconds to return or
>   time out. If your request contains a
>   host name that requires resolution and
>   you set Timeout to a value less than
>   15 seconds, it may take 15 seconds or
>   more before a WebException is thrown
>   to indicate a timeout on your request.

If it's possible that's the case? Try the sane code but using IP address instead of hostname.
Also, when you get `false` after waiting 20 seconds, are you sure it's because of timeout and not because the server returned something other than "200"?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried also with ip adress instead of hostname and the result is the same. But... I check if false is returning from "else" section, and it isn't. False is returning beacuse of exception "Limit of time of operation has expired".

Comment: When I tried to check f.eg. http://localhost/a.html when the server was on (but a.html doesn't exist) I got answer (404 error) immediately. But when I tried to check the same adress when the server was off I had to wait ~20 seconds and I got exception "Limit of the time...".

Comment: @Kuba: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Try this property: ReadWriteTimeout