# WebRequest.GetResponse() throws timeout exception even after setting timeout and the program waiting for the set duration

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, system.net.webexception

I try to get response codes from links which I extract from an email. I use the `System.Net` lib to accomplish the response code extraction. While debugging and testing my code I ran into the `System.Net.WebException "The operation has timed out"`  exception. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295017/c-sharp-httpwebresponse-timeout-doesnt-work) I have to set the timeout to a minimum of about 15 seconds because the DNS query can take up to 15 or more seconds to return the requested value.

In my code I set the timeout's value to 20 seconds (I tested with 60, then 30 seconds in before) and got the same timeout exception every try. I have to mention, that I request response codes from "similar" websites before I run into the timeout exceptions. This is the order of websites which I request information from:

1. https://www.google.com/
2. https://www.google.com/
3. https://www.google.de/
4. https://www.google.ded/ (=> throws exception as intended)
5. http://www.google.de/
6. http://www.google.de/
7. http://www.google.de/
8. http://www.google.de/
9. http://www.google.de/

7th request and following return: `WebException "The operation has timed out"`.

---

I assume that frequently requesting status codes from the same or similar link causes me to time out. Which leads me to my final questions:

> Do i have to set my timeout to a specific amount of time, are there limited amounts of request per client in a set time span, should it work if I am using similar links referring to different sites on a website (examples underneath) or is there a simple work-around to avoid these problems?

Examples:

`"foo.com/a" | "foo.com/b" | "foo.com/c" | "foo.com/a/d"`

---

## EDIT:

So I just tried to execute my code by using a new email which has several different links in it and I didn't run into any `WebException "The operation has timed out"` problems.

> Therefore I'd say that i get timeouts based on the amount of requests to a website in a short amount of time but I still have no exact explanation for this.
>
> Feel free to share your thoughts on this occurrence (and maybe explanations for what is happening exactly)

---

This is the code I use to get the response code:

```
public static List<LinkRespCode> GetStatusCodes(string mail)
    {
        List<LinkRespCode> li = new List<LinkRespCode>();
        try
        {
            Link[] obtainedLinks = Link_Obtainer.GetLinksTextHtml(mail);
            string[] links = new string[obtainedLinks.Length];
            var c = 0;
            foreach (Link link in obtainedLinks)
                links[c++] = link.HrefLink;
            string startUrl = "https://pastebin.com/", newLink = string.Empty;
            Uri uri = new Uri(startUrl);
            for(int i = 0; i < links.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!links[i].StartsWith("http://") && !links[i].StartsWith("https://"))
                        newLink = "http://" + links[i];
                    else
                        newLink = links[i];

                    uri = new Uri(newLink);

                    if (!uri.AbsoluteUri.Equals(startUrl) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newLink))
                    {
                        Uri uriResult;
                        if (Uri.TryCreate(newLink, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
                        {
                            obtainedLinks[i].HrefLink = uriResult.AbsoluteUri;
                            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriResult);
                            webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                            webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
                            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                            li.Add(new LinkRespCode(obtainedLinks[i], new StatusCode((int)response.StatusCode)));

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UriFormatException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("!!!ERROR: " + links[i] + " " + e.Message);
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("!!!ERROR: " + links[i] + " " + e.GetType() + " " + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return li;
    }
```

Comment: Does setting `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to 50 fix it?

Comment: `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` worked like a charm! Thanks! It would be awesome if you could add that as an answer so i can close this question.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit.aspx may be worth a read. In practice, the limit specifies how many concurrent requests can be made to a specific domain.

Comment: so if the requests are limited to a domain I have to include it even if there are parameters in the link since its target will always be the same server just aiming at different files based on the parameters

Comment: Correct. That is why bumping the number up solved your issue.