# HttpWebRequest's Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout -- What do these mean for the underlying TCP connection?

Tags: .net, tcp, httpwebrequest

I believe I understand the practical differences between `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` and `HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout`. However, I'm seeking *further* clarity on the difference between these two timeouts, including what these values mean with respect to the underlying **TCP** connection/buffers/state **if applicable**.

For instance, are these timeouts used only during the initialization of the TCP connection, or are these only managed values for keeping watch on the unmanaged connection?

What are the client-server scenarios in TCP terms where each of these timeouts would apply or not apply?

Answer (score 26):

This problem has been debated on another question, see [Adjusting HttpWebRequest Connection Timeout in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c-sharp).  The discussion made my head spin, so I'll offer my summary.

Although, MSDN explains that the [HttpWebRequest.Timeout Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) applies to `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` and `HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream` calls, the description is a bit confusing.

[Jim Mischel](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=573) is more helpful:  `Timeout` "is the time for the server to respond to a request, not the amount of time to wait for the server to respond and send down all of the data."  Thus, `Timeout` covers establishing a working connection.  For large payloads, this does not imply that the request/reply is complete.

`ReadWriteTimeout` applies to Read or Write operations to streams that transmit over the connection.  E.g. when you Write to the stream returned by GetRequestStream.  The connection is already established, but there is a risk that it will break.  E.g. the network connection goes down.

The Jim Mischel link has some very good advice on what values to set these timeout. I.e. the default for `ReadWriteTimeout` is too long.

Comment: Another tidbit of information: `HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout` works by setting the underlying `NetworkStream`'s `WriteTimeout` and `ReadTimeout` properties (learned by disassembling `System.Net`).

Comment: A thing that's worth mentioning is that `Timeout` encompasses the `ReadWriteTimeout`. If you have `Timeout` < `ReadWriteTimeout`, long running request may still timeout. I misunderstood that the first time...

Comment: @dstj default value of timeout = 100s while ReadWriteTimeout = 300s. So by default Timeout < ReadWriteTimeout.

Comment: Jim Mischel's article seems to have been removed from informit.com.  The Wayback Machine has it archived, though: https://web.archive.org/web/20160523140506/http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=573

Answer (score 8):

I believe you got the first part of your answer from @Donal Lafferty. Here's a quick summary anyway.

*HttpWebRequest.Timeout* - The time before which the server has to accept the client's request. Note that this doesn't include the DNS resolution time, which is managed by the ServicePointManager.

*HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout* - The time before which the client has to receive the entire body of the response from the server. Note that this timeout starts only after the server accepts the request.

The answer to your second question is two-folded.

**1. Synchronous request:**

The TCP connections are closed on timeout, everybody's happy.

**2. Asynchronous request:**

These timeouts have absolutely no effect. If you do not have an appropriate mechanism for handing the time-outs, the TCP connections will stay open.

That's precisely the reason why you Abort the request by registering a timeout on the AsyncWaitHandle, as shown in the example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/21k58ta7.aspx

Answer (score 6):

.Timeout = time spent trying to establish a connection (not including lookup time) .ReadWriteTimeout = time spent trying to read or write data after connection established

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers suggest changing the ReadWriteTimeout and the timeout.
Here's the Webclient override function you need to do this.

```
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            _request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            var httpRequest = _request as HttpWebRequest;
            httpRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 600000;
            httpRequest.Timeout = 600000;
            httpRequest.ContinueTimeout = 600000;
            if (_request != null)
            {
                httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = AutoRedirect;
                httpRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
                httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

                Setup?.Invoke(httpRequest);
            }

            return _request;
        }
```