# Fail Fast with WebClient

Tags: c#, webclient

Using a [modified WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052637/141172), I download data periodically from a service with the following characteristics:

- The data download (~1GB) can take around 20 minutes
- Sometimes the service decides not to return any data at all (request hangs), or takes minutes to hours to return the first byte.

I would like to fail fast in the event that the service does not return any data within a reasonable (configurable) amount of time, yet allow plenty of time for a download that is making progress to succeed.

It seems that the [WebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.timeout.aspx) property [controls the total time for the request to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121096/what-exactly-is-a-timeout-when-using-webrequest/11121587#11121587), while [ReadWriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout.aspx) controls the total time available to read data once the data transfer begins.

Am I missing a property that would control the maximum amount of time to wait between establishing the connection and the first byte returning?  If there is no such property, how can I approach the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any additional timeout property that will achieve the result you are looking for. The first thought that comes to mind is attaching a handler to `DownloadProgressChanged` that will update a flag to indicate data has been received (not always accurate though).

Using a `Timer` or `EventWaitHandle` you could then block (or handle async if you prefer) for a short period of time and evaluate whether any data has been received. The code below is not a fully fleshed out example, but an idea of how it may be implemented.

```
using (var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) => manualResetEvent.Set();
    client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("https://github.com/downloads/cbaxter/Harvester/Harvester.msi"));

    if (!manualResetEvent.WaitOne(5000))
        client.CancelAsync();
}
```

In the above example, the `manualResetEvent.WaitOne` will return `true` if `DownloadProgressChanged` was invoked. You will likely want to check `e.BytesReceived > 0` and only set for non-zero values, but I think you get the idea?

Comment: I was afraid that would be the exact answer :-(