# Timeout in web request doesn't seem to be honored

Tags: c#, timeout

I want my http get request to fail if it takes more than 10 seconds by timint out.

I have this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);

request.Method = "GET";
request.Timeout = 1000 * 10; // 10 seconds

HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable;

using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    httpStatusCode = webResponse.StatusCode;
}
```

It doesn't seem to timeout when I put a bad URL in the request, it just keeps going and going for a long time (seems like minutes).

WHy is this?

Comment: Timeout not applied to DNS queries?

Comment: Here is a similar question with good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing it in a web project, make sure the `debug` attribute of the `system.web/compilation` tag in the `Web.Config` file is set to "false".

If it is a console application or such, compile it in "Release" mode.

A lot of timeouts are ignored in "Debug" mode.

Comment: just looked and the web config doesn't have it set to true (so it defautls to false from what I read.

Comment: ok I explicitly set it to false just in case, still it took over 2 minutes and then I just cancelled it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably performing a DNS lookup on the bad URL which takes a minimum of 15 seconds.

According to the documentation for [HttpWebRequest.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx)

> A Domain Name System (DNS) query may take up to 15 seconds to return
>   or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires
>   resolution and you set Timeout to a value less than 15 seconds, it may
>   take 15 seconds or more before a WebException is thrown to indicate a
>   timeout on your request.

You can perform a DNS Lookup using [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but it looks like it will take 5 seconds by default.

Comment: the hostname is fine, I just adding 'asdf234' to the end of a url to see if the timeout is working.  like:  www.example.com/somepageasdf234234

Comment: Are you able to provide an exact URL you're using?