# WebRequest timed out in windows service

Tags: web-services, timeout, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I use WebRequest in a client to consume a web service on Internet. Each request is triggered in a separate thread.

It works well if hosting the client in IIS. But most of the requests will get timed out error if the client is hosted in a windows service.

When I tried to debug the problem using Fiddler, the WebRequest worked well as all traffic went through 127.0.0.1:8888

Without Fiddler, the traffic goes to Internet directly through a random port, and the time out problem hits again.

The windows service runs under Local System account.

Why do I get time out if the client is in windows service without using a proxy?

Update: My original question wasn't clear. The requests are made concurrently (or at a very short interval). This is to do with the connection limit in the ServicePoint class. By default only 2 connections are allowed to the same external destination. If the destination is local, the limit will be int.Max value. That's why fiddler can magically fix the problem with the proxy. So I manually set the DefaultConnectionLimit to 100 and the requests are on wire.

[Adjusting HttpWebRequest Connection Timeout in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

The most common source of problems that is "magically" fixed by running Fiddler is when your .NET code fails to call `Close()` on the object returned by `GetResponseStream()`. See http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/blog/13-02-28/help-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app.aspx for more details.