# Getting System.Net.WebException :The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, system.net.webexception, request-timed-out

I am working on a project in which i have to upload order from CSV file into database using batch process. Job is working prefect at back-end but suddenly a month ago it stop working, someone advice me to restart the server and it solves the issue but today again it stop working and I am getting the following error message-

> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse().

Here is the code for my trigger process -

```
  #region Trigger Batch Processor

            if (uploadedOrders.Count() == 0)
            {
                CommonLogging.InsertMessage(JobId, "No new orders to process", MessagingColor.Blue);

            }
            else
            {
                CommonLogging.InsertMessage(JobId, "New orders found - Trigger batch indexer", MessagingColor.Blue);
                var request = WebRequest.Create("http://myipaddress:8080/ProcessBatchFile/ProcessBatchFile.aspx");
                request.Timeout = 800000;
                request.GetResponse().Close();
               //  request.Abort();
            }
```

I used so many tricks but nothing work like increased the time-out time , abort the request, Close() the request.

Please help me out if anyone have idea.

Comment: The problem is in your server code, on ProcessBatchFile.aspx, not in the code you posted, post the asp code.

Comment: Increase ReadWriteTimeout see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c-sharp

Comment: ReadWriteTimeout doesnot work