# How to test Webrequest Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

My problem is for how do i test a Webrequest timeout . My C# code is making a SOAP service call to a 3rd party vendor whose code i do not have .  When their service goes down , most of my application URLs also go down as well.

So I thought of adding a timeout ; and read this blog as well which was helpful , but what would be the best way to test my code ?

[Adjusting HttpWebRequest Connection Timeout in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500955/adjusting-httpwebrequest-connection-timeout-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solved it using https://httpstat.us/

In my case I needed a 60 secs timeout so I made my request to https://httpstat.us/200?sleep=120000 and it worked.

Posted in case it is useful for anyone.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to an existing internet address but without using a standard port - a port where no service is running. This way the firewall should drop the packet and you should receive a timeout.

Eg. Use one of the big internet players but instead of port 80 (http) or 443 (https) use 354

Comment: Tried with https://google.com:354 and it throws an error saying nobody is listening, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a wrapper around the third part call and use the interface to mock your calls made to the third party so that you can return what you are expecting.